# Sending JKS file from open app to another using Spring Stack

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, jks

I'm looking for the Spring project which is providing some secure capability to sending JKS file between two Spring apps. I found a Spring Cloud Config project (currently I'm using it in my apps) and I found topics with same question in internet but no one answer it. Is there any feature that can I use from this project or maybe someone know another project with this features?

Answer (score 0):

There is no project that provides such capability AFAIK. You could serve the JKS file as a resource which is exposed at a certain web endpoint. Add Spring Security to your project so the other application can request the JKS file over HTTPS, and maybe add basic authentication for that specific web endpoint so others can't download it too.
Hope that helps!